# Upgrade to ember-typescript 3 complains about default parameters

Tags: typescript, ember.js

Our Ember components often use the following pattern which is working as expected with ember-typescript 2:

```
export default class DatePicker extends Component {
  format: string = this.format || 'dd/LL/yyyy';
}
```

If format is not passed via the template it is initialized with 'dd/LL/yyyy'.

With ember-typescript 3 and the newer TS version the compiler is not happy anymore. It complains with

```
error TS2729: Property 'format' is used before its initialization.
```

as it is not happy with the usage of `this.format`.

What should I do to solve this problem? Is our code (which works fine so far)  invalid and should be changed? If yes how?

Comment: Are you sure that this is related to an `ember-cli-typescript` update and not to an update of Ember itself? There was a change on the order of applying arguments passed to native classes described in [RFC Native Class Constructor Update](https://emberjs.github.io/rfcs/0337-native-class-constructor-update.html) and [shipped with Ember 3.6](https://blog.emberjs.com/2018/12/13/ember-3-6-released.html). Any chance that an update of `ember-source` < 3.5 to >= 3.6 causes that issue?

Comment: Just checked to be on the safe side: Simply upgrading typescript from 3.3.3 to 3.6.4 without touching any other dependencies already triggers the errors.  

We are on a commit slighly preceding Ember 3.12, so the RFC is already implemented. The interesting thing: The RFC mentions `bar = this.bar || 'baz';` as one of the valid (or at least used in the wild) ways to implement default parameters. If another aproach should be used I am happy enough to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have `this.format` as part of your default. Just do:

```
export default class DatePicker extends Component {
  format: string = 'dd/LL/yyyy';
}
```

If your template passes in `@format`, it will override the default you have in your component's TS file.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are absolutely right. No idea why this was written this way in the first place. Thanks!